# GoogleMaps 5.0 in android

Tags: java, android, maps

hi i want to use googlemaps 5.0 (3D view(Street view) )in my android app .is it possible .please share some resources or tutorial  that how to use them

Answer (score 0):

Have you already checked out googles official documentation?
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The Google Maps app and the maps add-on for app development are separate. The only thing you can do is open Google Maps to a given location via the *geo* or *google.streetview* [URI schemes](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html).